# Mongo error "out of bounds" for lng 180, lat 68.9636

Tags: mongodb, geojson

Getting the following error on MongoDB:

```
error MongoError: longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 180 lat: 68.9636
...
operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1590391393 },
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 180 lat: 68.9636',
code: 2,
codeName: 'BadValue',
'$clusterTime': {
  clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1590391393 },
  signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: 0 }
},
name: 'MongoError',
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
```

However, the bounds should be valid:

> If specifying latitude and longitude coordinates, list the longitude
>   first and then latitude:
>
> Valid longitude values are between -180 and 180, both inclusive. Valid
>   latitude values are between -90 and 90, both inclusive.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/

For reference, my query is

```
Profiles.find(
  {
    'features.geometry': {
      $geoIntersects: {
        $geometry: geometry
      }
    }
  }
).fetch()
```

(using Meteor)

The `geometry` can even be displayed:
https://gist.github.com/oleg131/19b17e25670d6a54a176a5c670fd9ce5

Has anyone seen this error for seemingly valid coordinates?

Comment: Btw, just fyi, same error in Mongo shell

Comment: How does your Geospatial Index look like?

Comment: When you insert your geometry at http://geojsonlint.com/ then you get `Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule`

Comment: Perhaps you could try inserting those polygons as separate objects to see if it is reject on its own, or only when combined with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some features had longitude *slightly* higher than 180, which was rounded off to 180 when displayed in the error traceback.